# Flutter and Material design 2

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there some chance to use Material Design 2 in Flutter?

I can't find any informations about this on official website.

For Android app are informations here: https://material.io/develop/android/

Comment: Most widgets should already comply to MD2. If you find something that doesn't, please create a bug report. Check also https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.flutter.demo.gallery

Comment: Ou :) sorry I didn't see it :) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you shouldn't completely copy Google's design, you can of course use some tweaks ;) Here are some I would recommend:

The package `rounded_modal`

Using `splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory` in your Theme, aswell as setting the `highlightColor: Colors.transparent`

Having the app bar the same color as the Scaffold background with no elevation (I would recommend a CustomScrollView)

Using `BottomNavigationBar` instead of a `Drawer`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a "Material Design 2.0" does not exist. It is just Google's personal version of Material Theming, which every brand should do for it's own design.

So I wouldn't recommend just copying Google's design standarts, come up with something creative by yourself ;)

All the components from [material.io](http://material.io) can be implemented and customized in Flutter with ease, just look up the documentation for the specified component.

The material design components in Flutter can be explored here: [material.io's Flutter specific site](https://material.io/develop/flutter/)